# Snort Rules configuration problems

Tags: debian, snort

Hi I just installed Snort on debian and configure it as random implementation as i don't know why is it not running afterall, could you reviev my configuration of Snort.
I run my snort by command (on Debian 10):

```
/usr/local/bin/snort -q -u snort -g snort -c /etc/snort/snort.conf -i wlp3s0
```

Started by wi-fi intel card - ip:

> 192.168.0.17

My snort.conf file changes:

```
# Setup the network addresses you are protecting
ipvar HOME_NET 192.168.0.17/24

# Set up the external network addresses. Leave as "any" in most situations
ipvar EXTERNAL_NET !$HOME_NET
```

I also include snort basic rules from community page, and random filters, but afterall in end process i've seen none...

As I said I seen in my pcap file - it doesn't work:
[wireshark PCAP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYg4e.png)

Answer (score 0):

On your HOME_NET variable definition, try using `ipvar HOME_NET 192.168.0.0/24`.

Using your machine's IP cannot work in this context because HOME_NET represents your local IP range with its IPv4 class definition (the `/24` means the 4th number is the variable part, which corresponds to a Class C IP).

Snort will then consider all IPs between 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.0.254 your home network.